# 2011 macbook pro not responding to startup commands

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

My macbook doesn't respond to any commands at startup (command + s, command+r, shift, command+alt+p+r). It wants to go straight to the apple logo then to a blue or white screen. Applecare is no longer on it. What should be my next step?

Comment: If you can, try attaching an external USB keyboard and see if that will work.

Answer (score 2):

Since the shift key or option key should be recognized by the system well before the Apple logo arrives, you can conclude that you have a failed keyboard.

Plugging in any USB keyboard and booting in safe mode (shift) or single user mode (command s) should let you know if the keyboard has issues.

Now the Apple and blue screen are good. They mean that the core OS and hardware are fine and that the start process is hung starting your user. My guess is you need to boot to internet recovery (or an external drive) and then repair some damage to the user files or the drive itself. Then you can delete the .AppleSetupDone file and make a new admin account to see if the Mac can work.

Answer (score 0):

You have experienced a graphics card failure due to poor manufacturing.  Read it and weep:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4766577?tstart=0

I just experienced the same problem.  You can boot in single-user mode and remove the AMD graphics card extensions, and your computer will boot with limited usability.

In order to get it repaired, I recommend a 3rd party repair shop.  Applecare wouldn't have helped you much in this situation, since they will only replace one defective part with another.  Find a shop in your area with good Yelp reviews, and ask them if they do "gpu reballing" - do not get it reflowed, it will only break again.  Good luck to you.  Hopefully, Apple will lose this next class action lawsuit and be forced to provide compensation to affected users.